# Make Buttons in GridLayout auto adjust

Tags: android, xml, button

I'm trying to make a series of buttons, kind of like a keyboard, for typing in playing cards. However, the size and position of the buttons in the gridlayout are different with every device I test it on. I'm looking for the best solution to spread the 3 columns across the screen. Any advice is appreciated. Also there may be a better way to do this than gridlayout which I'm open to. As you could probably guess, I'm new to android. Thanks in advance!

**XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="5">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonK"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="King"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonD"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Delete"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonG"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Go!"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="10"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonJ"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Jack"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonQ"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Queen"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="7"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="8"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="9"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="4"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="5"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="6"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonA"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Ace"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="2"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="3"/>
</GridLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Linearlayout is a good solution. You can use oriantation horizantal for rows and when button width is 0dp and weight is 1 it fits all screen sizes

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonK"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="King"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonD"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Delete"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonG"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Go!"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="10"/>
        
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonK1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="King"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonD1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Delete"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonG1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="Go!"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button101"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:text="10"/>

        </LinearLayout>
        
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In this layout, you can delete `RelativeLayout` tag and make first `LinearLayout` your root element.

Comment: That is fine but since the  developer  wants to create a keyboad I thought that  linearlayout should stay as keyboard layout